# mapstruct List<Object1> to List<Object2> with different attributes

Tags: mapstruct

I have to map List to List with different attribute names.

Ex:

```
public class Object1 {
   private String name; 

   //getters and setters
}


public class Object2 {
  private String customerName; 

  //getters and setters
}
@Mapping(source="object1List.name" target="object2List.customerName"
List<Object2> toObject2(final List<Object1> object1List)
```

I didn't write where I get Object1List to simplify. ( I get that in a different class in a method)

I have been trying this but mapstruct complains object1List is unknown property. Is there a way I can do this? Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

You need to declare a separate method for the mapping from `Object1` to `Object2`:

```
@Mapping(source="name" target="customerName")
Object object1ToObject2(Object1 object1)
```

Then declare your list mapping method (without the `@Mapping` annotation) and its generated implementation will invoke that method above for mapping the individual list elements.

Comment: If the separate method for the mapping from `Object1` to `Object2` is in another class you need declare the usage of that other class like so `@Mapper(uses = {AnotherClass.class})`